# Add only keys to an existing json array

Tags: javascript, json, key

I have a JSON array like the one below. Is it possible to add key values to each of the array with having to loop through each one? I want the arrays to have the same key value.

```
var r_list = [
    {
      "Column Name": "Name",
      "Value": "Some Name",
      "Some key": "Some Value",
      "Some other key": "Some other Value"
    },
    {
      "Column Name": "Age",
      "Value": 62,
      "Some key": "Some Value",
      "Some other key": "Some other Value"
    },
    {
      "Column Name": "Year",
      "Value": 1957,
      "Some key": "Some Value",
      "Some other key": "Some other Value"
    }
  ]
```

Expected output:

```
[
    12345: {
      "Column Name": "Name",
      "Value": "Some Name",
      "Some key": "Some Value",
      "Some other key": "Some other Value"
    },
    12345: {
      "Column Name": "Age",
      "Value": 62,
      "Some key": "Some Value",
      "Some other key": "Some other Value"
    },
    12345: {
      "Column Name": "Year",
      "Value": 1957,
      "Some key": "Some Value",
      "Some other key": "Some other Value"
    }
  ]
```

I tried this. `var final_list = r_list.map(r_list => ({12345: r_list}))`
but the result was not exactly in the format I wanted.

Comment: That's invalid though. repeating `12345` will override the previous key.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you want the same keys, just use an array?

Comment: And it is an array so that makes it even more wrong

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish? You're currently defeating the point of keys entirely, so there's probably a better way to do what you need.

Comment: And array cannot have keys, but you can create new res = {} and then just put elements of original like res[12345] = r_list[ x ] and eventually delete original r_list[ x ] then, but there is difference between array and associative array (number index vs. keys or [ ] vs { } in declaration) - you cannot mix them.